# Join new domain controller with

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain, iis-6

I recently created a new domain controller (Windows Server 2012 R2) that has the same domain name as the old controller (Windows Server 2000) and I have an old Windows Server 2003 with IIS/SQL and other miscellaneous services that I want to join the new domain without losing any of the websites/services that the current user and profile have.

When I switched all the workstations to the new domain I used a ForensIT profile wizard script to migrate their profiles to their new domain profile, that worked perfectly for the workstations.

Is there an easy way to join the Windows Server 2003 to the new domain?